# How can I code nullable objects in Google Cloud Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

This post is intended to answer questions like the following:

- Which built-in `Coder`s support nullable values?
- How can I encode nullable objects?
- What about classes with nullable fields?
- What about collections with `null` entries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can inspect the built-in Coders in the [DataflowJavaSDK source](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/tree/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/coders).

Some of the default Coders do not support `null` values, often for efficiency. For example, `DoubleCoder` always encodes a `double` using 8 bytes; adding a bit to reflect whether the `double` is `null` would add a (padded) 9th byte to all non-`null` values.

It is possible to encode nullable values using the techniques outlined below.

1. We generally recommend using [`AvroCoder`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/coders/AvroCoder.java) to encode classes. `AvroCoder` has support for nullable fields annotated with the `org.apache.avro.reflect.Nullable` annotation:

   ```
   @DefaultCoder(AvroCoder.class)
   class MyClass {
     @Nullable String nullableField;
   }
   ```

   See the [TrafficMaxLaneFlow](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/examples/complete/TrafficMaxLaneFlow.java) for a more complete code example.

   `AvroCoder` also supports fields that include `Null` in a `Union`.
2. We recommend using [`NullableCoder`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/coders/NullableCoder.java) to encode nullable objects themselves. This implements the strategy in #1.

   For example, consider the following working code:

   ```
   PCollection<String> output =
       p.apply(Create.of(null, "test1", null, "test2", null)
           .withCoder(NullableCoder.of(String.class)));
   ```
3. Nested `null` fields/objects are supported by many coders, as long as the nested coder supports `null` fields/objects.

   For example, the SDK should be able to infer a working coder using the default `CoderRegistry` for a `List<MyClass>` -- it should automatically use a `ListCoder` with a nested `AvroCoder`.

   Similarly, a `List<String>` with possibly-`null` entries can be encoded with the Coder:

   ```
   Coder<List<String>> coder = ListCoder.of(NullableCoder.of(String.class))
   ```

Finally, in some cases Coders must be deterministic, e.g., the key used for `GroupByKey`. In `AvroCoder`, the `@Nullable` fields are coded deterministically as long as the `Coder` for the base type is itself deterministic. Similarly, using `NullableCoder` should not affect whether an object can be encoded deterministically.

Comment: Code links need updated