# Unable to encode element 'org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaRecord@8b396a51' with coder 'KafkaRecordCoder(ByteArrayCoder,ByteArrayCoder)'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Team

Written the code in apache-beam  to read the messages from the Kafka. Please find the code below. With beam-nuggets library able to connect to the kafka and able to read the messages from Kafka.But with ReadFromKafka getting the below error.

Code is

```
from apache_beam.io.kafka import ReadFromKafka
from apache_beam.io.kafka import WriteToKafka
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import GoogleCloudOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import StandardOptions

from apache_beam  import window
import time
from time import sleep


options=PipelineOptions()
options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming=True
p=beam.Pipeline(options=options)

ReadMessage = (
                p
                |"Reading messages from Kafka" >> ReadFromKafka(consumer_config={'bootstrap.servers': "****.amazonaws.com:9096",'group.id': "roup_10", 'sasl.mechanism':"SCRAM-SHA-512","security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",'auto.offset.reset':'latest','sasl.jaas.config':"org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username='username1' password='password1';"}, topics=['test_topic'], key_deserializer='org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer', value_deserializer='org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer',expansion_service=None)
                |'Printing'>>beam.ParDo(print)
                )

result=p.run()
result.wait_until_finish()
```

Getting the error while executing the above code

```
WARNING:root:Make sure that locally built Python SDK docker image has Python 3.6 interpreter.
Trying to pull repository registry.access.redhat.com/apache/beam_java8_sdk ...
Pulling repository registry.access.redhat.com/apache/beam_java8_sdk
Trying to pull repository registry.redhat.io/apache/beam_java8_sdk ...
Trying to pull repository docker.io/apache/beam_java8_sdk ...
2.37.0: Pulling from docker.io/apache/beam_java8_sdk
Digest: sha256:bae6945b9a3309da607eab7eb73392aeb9fb49d8ed168b4b83e6ae9690710a81
Status: Image is up to date for docker.io/apache/beam_java8_sdk:2.37.0
E0601 12:09:10.605035310   22722 fork_posix.cc:76]           Other threads are currently calling into gRPC, skipping fork() handlers
E0601 12:09:11.639961240   24148 fork_posix.cc:76]           Other threads are currently calling into gRPC, skipping fork() handlers
E0601 12:09:16.671612766   24148 fork_posix.cc:76]           Other threads are currently calling into gRPC, skipping fork() handlers
ERROR:root:severity: ERROR
timestamp {
  seconds: 1654099760
  nanos: 301000000
}
message: "Exception while trying to handle InstructionRequest bundle_2"
trace: "org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to encode element \'org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaRecord@8b396a51\' with coder \'KafkaRecordCoder(ByteArrayCoder,ByteArrayCoder)\'.\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:39)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.outputTo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1772)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$2900(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:142)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$NonWindowObservingProcessBundleContext.outputWithTimestamp(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2328)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$ProcessBundleContextBase.output(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2498)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnOutputReceivers$WindowedContextOutputReceiver.output(DoFnOutputReceivers.java:78)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:142)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForParDo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:768)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:255)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:209)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.outputTo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1769)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$2900(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:142)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$WindowObservingProcessBundleContext.outputWithTimestamp(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2211)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnOutputReceivers$WindowedContextOutputReceiver.outputWithTimestamp(DoFnOutputReceivers.java:87)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.ReadFromKafkaDoFn.processElement(ReadFromKafkaDoFn.java:393)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.ReadFromKafkaDoFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForWindowObservingSizedElementAndRestriction(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1066)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$1500(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:142)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$4.accept(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:652)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$4.accept(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:647)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:255)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:209)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.BeamFnDataReadRunner.forwardElementToConsumer(BeamFnDataReadRunner.java:179)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.BeamFnDataInboundObserver2.multiplexElements(BeamFnDataInboundObserver2.java:158)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.BeamFnDataInboundObserver2.awaitCompletion(BeamFnDataInboundObserver2.java:123)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.ProcessBundleHandler.processBundle(ProcessBundleHandler.java:528)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient.delegateOnInstructionRequestType(BeamFnControlClient.java:151)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient$InboundObserver.lambda$onNext$0(BeamFnControlClient.java:116)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to encode element \'org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaRecord@8b396a51\' with coder \'KafkaRecordCoder(ByteArrayCoder,ByteArrayCoder)\'.\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.getEncodedElementByteSize(Coder.java:300)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.registerByteSizeObserver(Coder.java:291)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$SampleByteSizeDistribution.tryUpdate(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:374)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:248)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:209)\nCaused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderException: cannot encode a null byte[]\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.ByteArrayCoder.encode(ByteArrayCoder.java:63)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.ByteArrayCoder.encode(ByteArrayCoder.java:56)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.ByteArrayCoder.encode(ByteArrayCoder.java:41)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.KvCoder.encode(KvCoder.java:72)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.KvCoder.encode(KvCoder.java:63)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaRecordCoder.encode(KafkaRecordCoder.java:70)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaRecordCoder.encode(KafkaRecordCoder.java:40)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.getEncodedElementByteSize(Coder.java:297)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.registerByteSizeObserver(Coder.java:291)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$SampleByteSizeDistribution.tryUpdate(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:374)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:248)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:209)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.outputTo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1769)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$2900(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:142)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$NonWindowObservingProcessBundleContext.outputWithTimestamp(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2328)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$ProcessBundleContextBase.output(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2498)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnOutputReceivers$WindowedContextOutputReceiver.output(DoFnOutputReceivers.java:78)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:142)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForParDo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:768)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:255)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:209)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.outputTo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1769)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$2900(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:142)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$WindowObservingProcessBundleContext.outputWithTimestamp(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2211)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnOutputReceivers$WindowedContextOutputReceiver.outputWithTimestamp(DoFnOutputReceivers.java:87)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.ReadFromKafkaDoFn.processElement(ReadFromKafkaDoFn.java:393)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.ReadFromKafkaDoFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForWindowObservingSizedElementAndRestriction(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1066)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$1500(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:142)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$4.accept(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:652)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$4.accept(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:647)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:255)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:209)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.BeamFnDataReadRunner.forwardElementToConsumer(BeamFnDataReadRunner.java:179)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.BeamFnDataInboundObserver2.multiplexElements(BeamFnDataInboundObserver2.java:158)\n\tat org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.BeamFnDataInboundObserver2.awaitCompletion(BeamFnDataInboundObserver2.java:123)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.ProcessBundleHandler.processBundle(ProcessBundleHandler.java:528)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient.delegateOnInstructionRequestType(BeamFnControlClient.java:151)\n\tat org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient$InboundObserver.lambda$onNext$0(BeamFnControlClient.java:116)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)\n"
instruction_id: "bundle_2"
log_location: "org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient"
thread: "32"

E0601 12:09:20.937128080   22722 fork_posix.cc:76]           Other threads are currently calling into gRPC, skipping fork() handlers
WARNING:root:severity: WARN
timestamp {
  seconds: 1654099760
  nanos: 941000000
}
message: "Hanged up for url: \"localhost:46758\"\n."
log_location: "org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.BeamFnDataGrpcMultiplexer2"
thread: "25"

d9741741697d7d772f73e1d6839354722879ace01a72036a983a1263e6020845
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "KafkaIntegration.py", line 48, in <module>
    result=p.run()
  File "/home/gcp_cwlspr_test/bqloadenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 573, in run
    return self.runner.run_pipeline(self, self._options)
  File "/home/gcp_cwlspr_test/bqloadenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/direct/direct_runner.py", line 131, in run_pipeline
    return runner.run_pipeline(pipeline, options)
  File "/home/gcp_cwlspr_test/bqloadenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py", line 200, in run_pipeline
    pipeline.to_runner_api(default_environment=self._default_environment))
  File "/home/gcp_cwlspr_test/bqloadenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py", line 210, in run_via_runner_api
    return self.run_stages(stage_context, stages)
  File "/home/gcp_cwlspr_test/bqloadenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py", line 396, in run_stages
    runner_execution_context, bundle_context_manager)
  File "/home/gcp_cwlspr_test/bqloadenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py", line 667, in _run_stage
    bundle_manager))
  File "/home/gcp_cwlspr_test/bqloadenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py", line 784, in _run_bundle
    data_input, data_output, input_timers, expected_timer_output)
  File "/home/gcp_cwlspr_test/bqloadenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py", line 1134, in process_bundle
    raise RuntimeError(result.error)
RuntimeError: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to encode element 'org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaRecord@8b396a51' with coder 'KafkaRecordCoder(ByteArrayCoder,ByteArrayCoder)'.
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:39)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.outputTo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1772)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$2900(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:142)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$NonWindowObservingProcessBundleContext.outputWithTimestamp(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2328)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$ProcessBundleContextBase.output(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2498)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnOutputReceivers$WindowedContextOutputReceiver.output(DoFnOutputReceivers.java:78)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:142)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForParDo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:768)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:255)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:209)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.outputTo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1769)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$2900(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:142)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$WindowObservingProcessBundleContext.outputWithTimestamp(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2211)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnOutputReceivers$WindowedContextOutputReceiver.outputWithTimestamp(DoFnOutputReceivers.java:87)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.ReadFromKafkaDoFn.processElement(ReadFromKafkaDoFn.java:393)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.ReadFromKafkaDoFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForWindowObservingSizedElementAndRestriction(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1066)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$1500(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:142)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$4.accept(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:652)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$4.accept(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:647)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:255)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:209)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.BeamFnDataReadRunner.forwardElementToConsumer(BeamFnDataReadRunner.java:179)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.BeamFnDataInboundObserver2.multiplexElements(BeamFnDataInboundObserver2.java:158)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.BeamFnDataInboundObserver2.awaitCompletion(BeamFnDataInboundObserver2.java:123)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.ProcessBundleHandler.processBundle(ProcessBundleHandler.java:528)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient.delegateOnInstructionRequestType(BeamFnControlClient.java:151)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient$InboundObserver.lambda$onNext$0(BeamFnControlClient.java:116)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to encode element 'org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaRecord@8b396a51' with coder 'KafkaRecordCoder(ByteArrayCoder,ByteArrayCoder)'.
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.getEncodedElementByteSize(Coder.java:300)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.registerByteSizeObserver(Coder.java:291)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$SampleByteSizeDistribution.tryUpdate(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:374)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:248)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:209)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderException: cannot encode a null byte[]
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.ByteArrayCoder.encode(ByteArrayCoder.java:63)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.ByteArrayCoder.encode(ByteArrayCoder.java:56)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.ByteArrayCoder.encode(ByteArrayCoder.java:41)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.KvCoder.encode(KvCoder.java:72)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.KvCoder.encode(KvCoder.java:63)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaRecordCoder.encode(KafkaRecordCoder.java:70)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaRecordCoder.encode(KafkaRecordCoder.java:40)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.getEncodedElementByteSize(Coder.java:297)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.registerByteSizeObserver(Coder.java:291)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$SampleByteSizeDistribution.tryUpdate(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:374)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:248)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:209)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.outputTo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1769)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$2900(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:142)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$NonWindowObservingProcessBundleContext.outputWithTimestamp(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2328)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$ProcessBundleContextBase.output(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2498)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnOutputReceivers$WindowedContextOutputReceiver.output(DoFnOutputReceivers.java:78)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:142)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForParDo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:768)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:255)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:209)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.outputTo(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1769)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$2900(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:142)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$WindowObservingProcessBundleContext.outputWithTimestamp(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:2211)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnOutputReceivers$WindowedContextOutputReceiver.outputWithTimestamp(DoFnOutputReceivers.java:87)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.ReadFromKafkaDoFn.processElement(ReadFromKafkaDoFn.java:393)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.ReadFromKafkaDoFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.processElementForWindowObservingSizedElementAndRestriction(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:1066)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner.access$1500(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:142)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$4.accept(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:652)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.FnApiDoFnRunner$4.accept(FnApiDoFnRunner.java:647)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:255)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.data.PCollectionConsumerRegistry$MetricTrackingFnDataReceiver.accept(PCollectionConsumerRegistry.java:209)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.BeamFnDataReadRunner.forwardElementToConsumer(BeamFnDataReadRunner.java:179)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.BeamFnDataInboundObserver2.multiplexElements(BeamFnDataInboundObserver2.java:158)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.BeamFnDataInboundObserver2.awaitCompletion(BeamFnDataInboundObserver2.java:123)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.ProcessBundleHandler.processBundle(ProcessBundleHandler.java:528)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient.delegateOnInstructionRequestType(BeamFnControlClient.java:151)
        at org.apache.beam.fn.harness.control.BeamFnControlClient$InboundObserver.lambda$onNext$0(BeamFnControlClient.java:116)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Comment: Something in your data is null - `CoderException: cannot encode a null byte[]`... The key perhaps? Or maybe the value if you are using a compacted topic?

Comment: If it's unavoidable to have null values, you can use NullableCoder to enclose the default ByteArrayCoder. More details see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342402/how-can-i-code-nullable-objects-in-google-cloud-dataflow

Comment: @ningk I think part of the problem is that, by default, Kafka producers send null record keys.

Comment: I meant to say OP can override the default coder by enclosing it with a NullableCoder and register it: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#setting-default-coder.